# Two files with uneditable parts, is it possible to merge them?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Newbie to InDesign here, I was given two files for my work: a path version and a non-path version file, as shown in the picture. Here's the problem:

- For the non-path file, I can only edit the text but not the icons/graphics.
- For the path file, I can only edit the icons/graphics, but not the text.

How do I go about solving this as I want to edit both in one file? Is there a way to combine both files together somehow?

[image]

Comment: *Why* can't you edit the opposite parts? I mean, if it's just some locked layers, you can simply unlock the layers.

Comment: I am not sure either. Have checked, the layers aren't lock though!

Comment: Well, there's no way to "merge" specific parts of two separate InDesign files I'm aware of. But there's also no way to prevent editing of objects in an InDesign file if you have (at least the same version of) InDesign. If objects are un-selectable, they must be merely locked or on master pages.

Comment: Even if the _layers_ aren’t locked, individual _objects_ may be. Or, as Scott says, the objects may be on parent pages (called master pages up until recent versions).

Comment: .. another thought.... Check the Preferences for Indesign, the "General" section has an option -  `Prevent Selection of Locked Objects` - or something like that. This option is *on* by default I believe. That could be why you can't edit things.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no such thing** as an InDesign file where you cannot make edits on specific elements.

**100% everything is editable**, but there are indeed a few ways to lock layers **or** lock objects, to limit editing.

If you are sure the layers and **not** locked, try to see what happens when you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on a page where this problem exists.

Otherwise, do some research on unlocking layers **and** unlocking objects and you'll probably figure this out:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/grouping-locking-duplicating-objects.html
  https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/layers.html

Comment: also, if they are master-page items, then one can "override all master page items" (right-click the page(s)) in the pages palette to make them selectable